# Aws::S3::Errors::RequestTimeTooSkewed (The difference between the request time and the current time is too large.):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
storage: :s3,
:s3_region => 'ap-southeast-1',
s3_credentials: {
  bucket: 'sjoobing',
  access_key_id: '',
  secret_access_key: '',
}
}
```

When i upload file then gething this error

Answer (score 4):

The following works for me :

```
sudo apt-get install ntpdate
sudo ntpdate -s time.nist.gov
```

Answer (score 1):

The time on your server is out of sync with the current time. Sync up your system clock and the problem will go away.

Check this guide for syncing the timing

http://www.howtogeek.com/tips/how-to-sync-your-linux-server-time-with-network-time-servers-ntp/